# How to avoid using a hidden field for user_id in a Rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I feel like this should be an easy thing to do in Rails, but all of the examples of nested forms in Rails do not take into account the fact that most nested forms also need to pass the current_user when creating new objects through a nested form.

The only way I can get this to work at the moment is by passing a hidden field such as `<%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>`.

For my specific example, I have a model called "Result" that has many "Lessons" and I'd like to create new lessons through the Result form without passing a hidden `:user_id`.

This seems unsafe because someone could edit that hidden field in the browser and then submit the form thus associating the submission with a different user. The current_user.id seems like the type of thing you don't want to embed in the html as a hidden field.

So how do you create the association between the nested objects and the current_user without putting that hidden field in the form?

FYI, I'm using the [GoRails nested form with stimulus](https://gorails.com/episodes/dynamic-nested-forms-with-stimulus-js) style javascript to add and remove lessons from the result form. ([Here's the source code for that example](http://%20https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/dynamic-nested-forms-with-stimulusjs).) Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**models/result.rb**

```
class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lessons, inverse_of: :result

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**models/lesson.rb**

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :result
end
```

**controllers/results_controller.rb**

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_result, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @result = Result.new
    @result.lessons.new
  end

  def create
    @result = current_user.results.new(result_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_result
      @result = Result.find(params[:id])
    end

    def result_params
      params.require(:result).permit(:prediction_id, :post_mortem, :correct,
                                     lessons_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :summary, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**controllers/lessons_controller.rb**

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /lessons/new
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end

  def create
    @lesson = current_user.lessons.new(lesson_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_lesson
      @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:result_id, :summary)
    end
end
```

**views/results/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: result, local: true) do |form| %>

  <h3>Lessons</h3>

  <div data-controller="nested-form">
    <template data-target="nested-form.template">
      <%= form.fields_for :lessons, Lesson.new, child_index: 'NEW_RECORD' do |lesson| %>
        <%= render "lesson_fields", form: lesson %>
      <% end %>
    </template>

    <%= form.fields_for :lessons do |lesson| %>
      <%= render "lesson_fields", form: lesson %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="pt-4" data-target="nested-form.links">
      <%= link_to "Add Lesson", "#",
                  data: { action: "click->nested-form#add_association" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-submit">
   <%= form.submit "Save" %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

**views/results/_lesson_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "nested-fields", data: { new_record: form.object.new_record? } do %>
  # This hidden field seems unsafe!
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  <div class="pb-8">
    <%= form.text_area :summary %>
    <%= link_to "Remove", "#", 
                data: { action: "click->nested-form#remove_association" } %>
  </div>

  <%= form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<% end %>
```

I'm sure this is a common problem in Rails but I can't find any tutorials online that have the user_id as a part of the nested fields example. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have  users sessions in your app?  If so, `current_user` should be present on any controller action and not need to be passed at all as a param right?

Comment: yes, I have `current_user` available to all controllers, but I still have to create the association between the nested lessons and the user. That's the problem. I get a "Lessons user must exist" error when I try to submit the form.

Comment: will `@lesson.user_id` always be `current_user.id` ?

Comment: not necessarily, but it will always be true on create, update, or destroy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, since setting the current_user id is something the controller should care about, I would iterate over all the lessons and set the user_id value there.

```
def create
  @result = current_user.results.new(result_params)
  @result.lessons.each do |lesson|
    lesson.user ||= current_user if lesson.new_record?
  end

  ... the rest ...
```

Having a hidden field is a security risk, someone could edit it. I also don't like changing the params hash.

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked, but now I'm getting a similar error on the update action, so what would be a DRY to handle editing this same form?

Comment: I guess you could create a private method on your controller to do that little lessons loop fix (like `def set_lessons_user; @result.lessons.... `) and just call that method on both your actions. Since it only sets the user if `new_record?` it should be safe.

Comment: hmm. that is not working. I'm getting the same "Lessons user must exist" error on update even if I put the same loop in the update action. It's only working on create now. Been playing around with this and don't understand why.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this update action is not working: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/65dc3b4dd58f11b304c9069be50e5728

Comment: You are setting the current_user on lessons before actually setting them. Do something like `@result.attributes = result_params`, then the loop, and then `if @result.save`

Comment: Yep that did it. Here is the version of the update action that worked: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/02438e2a04367ae57e57761abc9f0178

Comment: I would change the answer to: `@result.lessons.select(&:new_record?).each { |lesson| lesson.user ||= current_user }` but this is just personal preference.

Comment: @3limin4t0r you are looping twice that way, once to filter and once to set the user.

Comment: @arieljuod Correct, however I prefer readability over performance to start of. Optimizations can always be done later down the line.

Comment: For me, a single loop with an explicit action on each iteam is more readable than chaining methods. Like you said, it's just personal preference.

Comment: Late to the show but could you explain or point me in the right direction why in the update method `@result.save` works but `@result.update` does not? Much appreciated. @arieljuod or Lee if you know

Comment: `@result.save` and `@result.update` do different things, you need to share more context and maybe logs, it's impossible to know

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot now. The reason it failed or at least how i discern it, I was assigning the attributes in the edit method thinking they would pass through to the update when post/patching. Also I know this post was from 2019 but I assign the attributes with `@results.assign_attributes(result_params)`. Was the way you assigned attributes the rails way back then?  Just to clarify to anyone @arieljuod early comment explanation works

Comment: I don't remember exactly, I think you an use `assign_attributes(...)` or `attributes = ...`, I don't know if there's any difference

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a great way to handle this automatically outside of the view. You would either have to inject the value unto the params or possible have a use `default` on the `user` association in Lesson that sets it from the Record's user (`belongs_to :user, default: -> { result.user }`). In these scenarios, I generally move outside of the default Rails flow and use a PORO, Form Object, service object, etc.

Comment: So is it a common pattern in Rails to just leave it in the view like this? It felt wrong as I was doing it.

Comment: No, normally you would revisit your data model to see if that field is necessary or do one of the other two methods I said. I believe Basecamp uses [Current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html) I believe to handle this.

Comment: What is a more common way in rails to model your app if you want to scope everything to the user's account. I was just assuming that you would want any object to belong_to User. Would you still do this, but then use Current on your create action, similar to the rails api example, `Current.account.messages.create(message_params)`

Comment: In general you need to look at your data model and see if there is a way to efficiently get from A to B or C if only one of them has a user association. In your case since `Result` `belongs_to :user` you can get all of the lessons by going through the `Result` model. `Lesson.joins(:result).where(results: { user_id: current_user.id }).first` or whatever you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

build form like this

```
<%= form.fields_for :lessons, lesson_for_form(current_user.id) do |lesson| %>
  <%= render "lesson_fields", form: lesson %>
<% end %>
```

remove hidden user_id field you have added

update your result.rb file

```
 class Result < ApplicationRecord

   def lesson_for_form(user_id)
     collection = lessons.where(user_id: user_id)
     collection.any? ? collection : lessons.build(user_id: user_id)
   end

 end
```